# Just one marker on Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps iOS SDK in my iOS app, everything is fine, and i wondering how i can tap the map and add just one marker, right now there is a marker overtime that i tapped.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        marker.title = "my title"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want only one marker on the map at a time? or you just want to allow One more (so two including the one you already have) only?

Comment: @KayAnn, in this map i need just one marker, i don't care how many the user tapped the map, i need just one marker there, i did using mapView.clear(), i don't know if is the best solution, but look fine right now.

Comment: didTapAtCoordinate is an optional method. So I guess just like setting clickable to false if you do not use this method it should either make it not clickable or at least it wouldn't return the coordinate. I'm not sure about it though.

Comment: hahah ok, i need the coordinate, i just need one marker, but i did it  in didTapAtCoordinate, using Clear()

Comment: ok well. sure! I am not too well versed with iOS but as long as it works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are Making a new Marker on every time you tap on the Map, 
So multiple objects are being created, so create only one object (declare it Global in your class) and you are good to go !

call this method in your Function .

```
marker1.position = coordinate
marker1.title = "Yo Man"
marker1.map = mapView
```

Comment: Thank you Dev : I have created like  this let marker1 = GMSMarker()